# cabac : decoding error

Tags: camera, opencv, video-streaming, rtsp

I am using an IP camera , opened in OpenCV. While displaying the output of the Camera I'm getting errors like ;

`[h264 @ 0xd1c440] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 42
[h264 @ 0xd1c440] error while decoding MB 0 42, bytestream (0)
[h264 @ 0xd1c000] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 50 40
[h264 @ 0xd1c000] error while decoding MB 50 40, bytestream (-1)
[h264 @ 0xd1c440] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 101 21
[h264 @ 0xd1c440] error while decoding MB 101 21, bytestream (0)
[h264 @ 0xd1c440] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 35 6
[h264 @ 0xd1c440] error while decoding MB 35 6, bytestream (-1)
[h264 @ 0xde49c0] cabac decode of qscale diff failed at 28 53
[h264 @ 0xde49c0] error while decoding MB 28 53, bytestream (15141)`

Can anyone suggest what going on and how to fix this ?

Thanks 
Sam

Comment: Update the software?

Comment: OpenCV? Its 3.1 already

Comment: Can you watch the output of the camera in ffmpeg? If yes, I am afraid, you will have to setup the online decoding with ffmpeg into YUV stream, and send that to your OpenCV. Not every h264 is actually h264.